# mongodb pymongo geonear results loop

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

im using geonear to get a list of results from mongodb (with distance included)
this is what i get back

```
[{u'obj': {u'_id': ObjectId('5210bc7fa861b40ba0745c1b'), u'loc': {u'type': u'Point',
u'coordinates': [1.063122, 51.856272]}}, u'dis': 0.0044619326805318904}, 
{u'obj': {u'_id': ObjectId('5210c1f9a861b40ba0745c1e'), u'loc': {u'type': u'Point',
u'coordinates': [0.933004, 51.90634]}}, u'dis': 10536.105585810197}]
```

my problem is that im not able to loop through the results and display each document 
i believe it is because it is returning a list rather than a dict is that correct ?

how would i loop through and display the results

many thanks

Rob

Comment: Thanks for asking, got the direction from @llovett's answer to solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

The [pymongo geospatial examples](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/geo.html?highlight=geonear#querying) indicate that a `$geoNear` query returns a dictionary that contains the results as well as status, query statistics, and other data. So you could loop through just the results like:

```
for result in db.command(SON([("geoNear", "places") ("near", [0.933004, 51.90634])]))["results"]:
    # do something with result here
```

Answer (score 0):

`$geoNear`

is supposed to return a documents, at least this is what the documentation claims:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/geoNear/

"$geoNear returns documents in order of nearest to farthest from a specified point and pass the documents through the aggregation pipeline."